# Memory consumption of python lists of lists

Tags: python, memory

A code I was recently working on was found to be using around `200MB` of memory to run, and I'm stumped as to why it would need that much.

Basically it mapped a text file onto a list where each character in the file was its own list containing the character and how often it has shown up so far (starting from zero) as its two items.

So `'abbac...'` would be `[['a','0'],['b','0'],['b','1'],['a','1'],['c','0'],...]`

For a text file 1 million characters long, it used 200MB.

Is this reasonable or was it something else my code was doing? If it is reasonable, was it because of the high number of lists? Would `[a,0,b,0,b,1,a,1,c,0...]` take up substantially less space?

Comment: Is it important to have multiple entries for each character? In you example, would it be sufficient to have `[a,2], [b,2], [c,1]...`, simply counting the occurrences for each character?

Comment: How did you measure your memory usage?

Comment: I'm a little hesitant seeing how it's an assignment that others have yet to finish. Is it necessary?

Comment: top command in linux

Comment: I should mention that my code does a lot more than just that, it just seemed like the only part that could take up that much space to me.

Comment: It is important to have separate records for each character.

Comment: as @OdiegoSilva mentioned, are you forced to count the occurrences case by case?

Comment: Yes. I'm forced to. I need to know the index the individual letter showed up in.

Comment: Maybe a dictionary where letter is the key and then add values based on the occurrence.

Comment: How about this: approx how much space would a '[[['a','0'],['b','0'],['b','1'],['a','1'],['c','0'],...]' list take for 1 million characters vs a '[a,0,b,0,b,1]' ?

My algorithm needs to be able to access a particular character via index and know how many times it had been mentioned before this point in constant time. My implementation does so, only takes too much space.

Comment: You could save a bit of space using a list of tuples instead of a list of lists - and semantically your sublists _are_ tuples -, but it will still eat quite some memory.  If you dont need to keep the whole list in memory, a generator might just be the ticket.

Else, another possible data structure could be a dict mapping letters to a list of `(index, appearances_so_far)` tuples but I'm not sure it would save that  much space (nor even it would save any).

Comment: OK, so I'm clear: it makes sense that a 1 million long list of 2 item lists takes up >100MB and that a 2 million long list will take about the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need the list itself, then I fully subscribe @Lattyware's solution of using a generator.

However, if that's not an option then perhaps you could compress the data in your list without loss of information by storing only the positions for each character in the file.

```
import random
import string

def track_char(s):
    # Make sure all characters have the same case
    s = s.lower()
    d = dict((k, []) for k in set(s))
    for position, char in enumerate(s):
         d[char].append(position)
    return d

st = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(50000))
d = track_char(st)

len(d["a"])

# Total number of occurrences of character 2
for char, vals in d.items():
    if 2 in vals:
         print("Character %s has %s occurrences" % (char,len(d[char]))
Character C has 1878 occurrences

# Number of occurrences of character 2 so far
for char, vals in d.items():
    if 2 in vals:
        print("Character %s has %s occurrences so far" % (char, len([x for x in d[char] if x <= 2))
Character C has 1 occurrences so far
```

This way there is no need to duplicate the character string each time there is an occurrence, and you maintain the information of all their occurrences.

To compare the object size of your original list or this approach, here's a test

```
import random
import string
from sys import getsizeof

# random generation of a string with 50k characters
st = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(50000))

# Function that returns the original list for this string
def original_track(s):
    l = []
    for position, char in enumerate(s):
        l.append([char, position])
    return l

# Testing sizes
original_list = original_track(st)
dict_format = track_char(st)

getsizeof(original_list)
406496
getsizeof(dict_format)
1632
```

As you can see, the dict_format is roughly 250x times smaller in size. However this difference in sizes should be more pronounced in larger strings.

Comment: Thanks very much. Would I be right in saying it would take around half the space of a '[a,0,b,0,b,1,a,1,c,0...]' list since the letters only show up once each but there still need to be n items in the lists all together?

Comment: It depends on the size of the string. I'll update the post with some tests

Comment: argh on second thought, my list is still needed because only '[a,0,b,0,b,1,a,1,c,0...]'  can tell you how many times the nth letter in the file has shown up in constant time. Unless I'm wrong.

Comment: It's still possible with the dict format, though less simple than with a list. I'll update

Comment: Just to make sure, I mean so far, not in total. The number to the right of the nth letter in the list.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but doesn't the inclusion of for loops mean the process takes longer than accessing list[n+1]? The list implementation is O(C), which is important.

Comment: Yes, it will take longer. On the other hand, creating the original list will also take longer than creating the dictionary. Moreover, in your case there will be a maximum of 26 iterations if the string contains all the letters of the alphabet, and the for loop will be done almost instantly. With a string with 1M characters, the for loop takes about .22 seconds to finish.

Comment: ahh but you see that loop needs to be accessed 1 million times :(

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to memory use and lists, one of the best ways to reduce memory usage is to avoid lists at all - Python has great support for iterators in the form of generators. If you can produce a generator instead of constructing a list, you should be able to do something like this with very little memory usage. Of course, it depends what you are doing with the data afterwards (say you are writing this structure out to a file, you could do so piece by piece and not store the entire thing at once).

```
from collections import Counter

def charactersWithCounts():
    seen = Counter()
    for character in data:
        yield (character, seen[character])
        seen[character] += 1
```